# Accelerometer.GetDefault(AccelerometerReadingType.Linear) parameter return null - UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, accelerometer, sensors

I'm trying to get Linear acceleration from my surface 3 by calling `Accelerometer.GetDefault(AccelerometerReadingType.Linear)` but it returns `null`.
I noticed with default parameter it works fine though.
I don't find any proper documentation that explains why this happening.
Is there anyway to filter the acceleration without gravity in UWP?

Comment: It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer) it will return null if no device found. So, if it is working fine with default parameters but returns null when you pass `AccelerometerReadingType.Linear`, it might be a bug.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin Yes I read this before and I found nothing important. anyway even with passing AccelerometerReadingType.Gravity it return null and only with AccelerometerReadingType.Standard it passed the default.